# How do I compile the go compiler statically?

Tags: go

How do I compile the go compiler statically with CGO support?

Compiling the sources with CGO_ENABLED=0 and GO_LDFLAGS='-extldflags "-static"'  results in a statically linked binary:

```
../bin/go: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

However, using the linker flags and CGO_ENABLED=1 does not produced a statically linked binary.

This is what I have done so far:

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim AS builder                                                                                                   

ENV CGO_ENABLED=1                                                                                                                     
ENV GO_LDFLAGS='-extldflags "-static"'                                                                                                
ENV GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/local/go                                                                                                    
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y curl git build-essential make cmake                                                
RUN curl -fLOSs "https://dl.google.com/go/go1.9.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz" \                                                               
&& tar -C /usr/local -xzf "go1.9.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz"                                                                                
RUN git clone https://go.googlesource.com/go \                                                                                        
&& cd go \                                                                                                                            
&& git checkout go1.9.3 \                                                                                                             
&& cd src \                                                                                                                           
&& ./make.bash                                                                                                                        
RUN apt install -y file && /usr/bin/file /go/bin/go                                                                                   


FROM scratch                                                                                                                         
ENV GOPATH=/code                                                                                                                     
COPY --from=builder /go/bin /usr/local/go/bin                                                                                        
CMD ["/usr/local/go/bin/go"]
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't need cgo, so just build it with `CGO_ENABLED=0`. You don't need `'-extldflags "-static"'` at all, because it's not invoking an external linker, because there's no cgo.

Comment: I thought of CGO as some kind of "feature gate" to en- or disable the CGO functionality?

Comment: yes, that's the point, you're disabling that functionality while building the go toolchain. It also sets the default in `go env`, but it doesn't effect what the go tool or the compiler have the ability to build.

Comment: hmm looks like the go docs disagree concerning cgo https://golang.org/doc/install/source#ccompiler

Comment: I don't understand how you mean that disagrees. That is exactly matches what I've said.